# rooted android device freezes when writing to /system

Tags: android, shell, rooted-device

I try to replace the build.prop in the system partition of my android device and it fezzes. 
I have rooted a samsung tablet sm-T850 with twrp_3.1.0-1_sm-t825_5417 and SR3-SuperSU-v2.82-SR3-20170813133244

the commands I have used to do this is :

```
gts3llte:/system # mount -o rw,remount /system

gts3llte:/ # mount -v | grep system

/dev/block/mmcblk0p44 on /system type ext4 (rw,seclabel,nosuid,noatime,norecovery)
gts3llte:/system # dd if=/sdcard/build.prop of=/system/build.prop

FREZZES!
```

device details:

- Galaxy Tab S3 (SM T825)
- Android 7 Linux version 3.18.31-11628211
- su version   2.82 also tried 2.79

Other symptoms:

- same happens with mv and cp
- I can create files in /system
- I can append text to /system/ build.prop
- if I reboot the tablet the new files are gone
- I have also tried with busybox’s mount and dd having the same results

Any ideas on whats wrong?
Many thanks!

Comment: having this same issues on a lenovo tablet - did you ever get this?

Comment: I wonder if dm-verity / verified boot is getting in your way. As of Android 7, verified boot can even do error correcting so could explain why files disappear on reboot.

https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2016/07/strictly-enforced-verified-boot-with.html

I wonder if you can find way to check status and/or disable dm-verity?